# Itext New Font with Bold and Underline

Tags: java, fonts, itext

I am trying to add new font to my pdf which I need to make it bold and underlined..

I can add the new Font, but cannot make it bold and underlined at same time.

I tried the following way..

```
public class PdfGenerator {

    private static final String BASE_FONT = "Trebuchet MS";
    private static final String BASE_FONT_BOLDITALIC = "Trebuchet MS BI";
    private static final String BASE_FONT_BOLD = "Trebuchet MS B";

    private static final Font titlefontSmall = FontFactory.getFont(
            BASE_FONT_BOLD, 10, Font.UNDERLINE);

    static {
        String filePath = "..my font directory";
        String fontPath = filePath + "\\" + "trebuc.ttf";
        String fontPathB = filePath + "\\" + "TREBUCBD.TTF";
        String fontPathBI = filePath + "\\" + "TREBUCBI.TTF";

        FontFactory.register(fontPath, BASE_FONT);
        FontFactory.register(fontPathB, BASE_FONT_BOLD);
        FontFactory.register(fontPathBI, BASE_FONT_BOLDITALIC);
    }

    public void genMyPdf(String filePath) {
        try {
            Document document = new Document();
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document,
                    new FileOutputStream(filePath));
            document.open();

            Paragraph p = new Paragraph("This should be bold & underline",
                    titlefontSmall);
            document.add(p);
            document.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (DocumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Read up on **[HERE](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-itext/underline-strikethrough.html)** since you are using the IText library.

Basically use chunks then add those chunks to the document.

```
Chunk underline = new Chunk("Underline. ");
underline.setUnderline(0.1f, -2f); //0.1 thick, -2 y-location
document.add(underline);
```

I haven't tried it myself so I don't know how it turns out yet. *Further reading up on the iText documentation*, it seems that you have to define a bold font first and then implement it. **[THIS TUTORIAL](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=212)** shows an example of  bold font usage with iText and making a pdf with bold text. From there, I'm sure you can implement the code above to the bold text and walah!, bold-underlined text :D

Answer (score 22):

you can define a font object with both styles :

```
private static final Font SUBFONT = new Font(Font.getFamily("TIMES_ROMAN"), 12,    Font.BOLD|Font.UNDERLINE);
```

Comment: It makes helpful and less code effort. thanks @carlos

Answer (score 2):

You can define your FONT in your class as such:

```
 public final static Font CUSTOM_FONT = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 8, Font.BOLD | Font.UNDERLINE);
```

and then use it as :

```
paragraph.add(new Phrase( " YOUR TEXT HERE ",PDFCreator.CUSTOM_FONT));
```

Answer (score 1):

try it

```
Font fontbold = FontFactory.getFont("Times-Roman", 12, Font.BOLD);
        document.add(new Paragraph("Times-Roman, Bold", fontbold));
```

and Font.UNDERLINE for undeline

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the following to get both bold and underline:-

```
Chunk buyerOrder = new Chunk("Buyer's Order Number", FontFactory.getFont(FontConstants.TIMES_ROMAN,8,Font.BOLD));
buyerOrder.setUnderline(0.1f, -2f);
```

Hope it helps! Thanks